# StackView - center buttons with text below image

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout, uistackview

I am using this class for center text below icon for `UIButton`:

```
@IBDesignable
class TopIconButton: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let kTextTopPadding:CGFloat = 3.0;

        var titleLabelFrame = self.titleLabel!.frame;


        let labelSize = titleLabel!.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.contentRect(forBounds: self.bounds).width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        var imageFrame = self.imageView!.frame;

        let fitBoxSize = CGSize(width: max(imageFrame.size.width, labelSize.width), height: labelSize.height + kTextTopPadding + imageFrame.size.height)

        let fitBoxRect = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: (self.bounds.size.width - fitBoxSize.width)/2, dy: (self.bounds.size.height - fitBoxSize.height) / 2)

        imageFrame.origin.y = fitBoxRect.origin.y
        imageFrame.origin.x = fitBoxRect.midX - (imageFrame.size.width/2)
        self.imageView!.frame = imageFrame;

        // Adjust the label size to fit the text, and move it below the image

        titleLabelFrame.size.width = labelSize.width
        titleLabelFrame.size.height = labelSize.height
        titleLabelFrame.origin.x = (self.frame.size.width / 2) - (labelSize.width / 2)
        titleLabelFrame.origin.y = fitBoxRect.origin.y + imageFrame.size.height + kTextTopPadding
        self.titleLabel!.frame = titleLabelFrame
        self.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
    }
}
```

It's working fine. My problem is when I start using in `UIStackView`. I am creating something similar to `UITabBar` so I have 5 buttons next to each other. I want to middle button be in exact center of screen but it's always several pixels to side. I check my constraints for `UIStackView` and it's okay. I remove all buttons exect middle one and then it's in exact middle. I tried different options for `UIStackView` (Fill, Centered, Fill Equally, etc.). Nothing helps. Do anyone has any idea? Each button has different icon (with different size) and texts are different too (free, premium, etc. - sometimes bigger then icon sometimes smaller), is this relevant?

Example of my StackView (red line shows where is middle):

[image: Example of my StackView]

Answer (score 0):

The image size is going to be relevant here. Once you get all 5 images to be the same exact size you won't experience this issue anymore. Using 'fill equally' after doing that and you will get the result you want